# running jvmtop profile & the JAVA_HOME environment variable

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk

### **Note:** It seems jvmtop is simply broken with Java 11. I would also accept alternative Java process profiling options for Ubuntu 20.04 (terminal only) & Java 11, if instructions for installation and execution are clear.

jvmtop requires `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to a valid JDE.

I tried to setup `JAVA_HOME` on `~/.profile`'s last line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

so it was permanent.

However, on executing: `bash jvmtop.sh --profile <PID>`
I got this: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin seems to be no JDK!`

**Update1:** I made the environment path permanent thanks to instructions from answer.
The error still shows up though:

```
network@ns3009333:~/jvmtop$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
network@ns3009333:~/jvmtop$ bash jvmtop.sh --profile 7435
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin seems to be no JDK!
```

**Update2:** I've tried appending the following 3 commands in diferent ocasions, to ~/.profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The message is still "seems to be no JDK!" (I made sure I logged back in).

**Update3:** Also tried setting
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
in
`nano jvmtop.sh`
as seen in a tutorial I found. Same negative results.

**Update4:** I thought my JDE was maybe not installed properly, so I reinstalled Java JDK and JDE. I currently have java 11 fully installed and confirmed working (no other java versions, just 11). I've also verified the folder `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` pointed to by the path actually exists and has contents.

I also tried executing the jvmtop.sh with both `./` and `bash`
Error message is the same.

Current setup is:
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
added to
`nano jvmtop.sh`
line 10, and then executing jvmtop.sh pointing to a valid process ID.

**Update5:** I finally decided to just open a github ticket on jvmtop, and surely enough, after I did, I found out someone had already done it, on the same issue:
https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop/issues/119

Comment: Then it's more into it. Hopefully someone is able to help.

Comment: Please can you test to set the path JAVA_HOME without `bin`? So in your case `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/`

Comment: Same:
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/ seems to be no JDK!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to successfully run jvmtop to profile a Java Process on Ubuntu**

First download and extract jvmtop, link: https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop

jvmtop has no guarantee of working well with Java versions above 8.
In order to make sure you are using Java 8:

```
apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

You can see all java versions installed, and switch to one of them with:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Make sure you're using java 8.

Go to the directory where you downloaded and extracted jvmtop.

The JAVA_HOME environment variable must point to a valid JDK, for jvmtop to work.
Easy way, Just:

```
nano jvmtop.sh
```

add to line 10:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

or equivalent path to java 8.

Check for the process ID that you want to profile using command

```
ps -aux
```

Once you find out the process ID, run:

```
bash jvmtop.sh --profile <PID>
```

You can skip the pid and it will just profile all java processes.